# On IIS6, can I install a certificate on a website with another CSR pending?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, ssl-certificate, csr

I have a GoDaddy exteneded EV certificate that I am trying to renew. It had completely expired before I realized it was up for renewal. In a haste, I generated a CSR to issue a new certificate from the web site where the original certificate was installed.

After a few days went by, I realized that they also allow the creation of a temporary certificate for use during the 10 day EV approval process. While I can easily create a CSR and then generate and export the certificate into a file, I am puzzled how I can add the certificate back to the original site without deleting the current CSR request (for the EV certificate) that is there.

I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/208507/installing-a-certificate-without-the-csrs-originating-website-in-iis-6) indicating I can generate the certificate without the original pending CSR using command line utilities, but I would rather not resort to that if there is another way to install the certificate without deleting the pending CSR.